# random function in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am currently using DrRacket on Mac OS X and choose the language "R5RS", but when I enter

```
(random 100)
```

I get the error message:

```
reference to undefined identifier: random
```

What's the problem here? Is it caused by a missing package?

Comment: I also tried random-integer and random-float, but got the same response.

Comment: I found the solution, the packet is available in PLaneT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is ‘random‘ a function provided by R5RS?  I look for it in the index of the [spec](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/), but I don't see it there.  R5RS is a minimal language mode, and when Racket is in R5RS mode, it really restricts itself.

Racket does have a native [random](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=Random#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._random%29%29) function.  If you are using ‘#lang racket‘, it's automatically available.  Is there a reason you're using the R5RS language mode?

Answer (score 10):

As dyoo points out, the function `random` is not defined in R5RS.
If you want to use "foreign" functions in the R5RS language in DrRacket,
you can use `#%require` to import them.

In this case search for `random` in the Racket documentation. Notice that `random` is part of the module `racket/base`. Now write:

```
(#%require (only racket/base random))
(random 10)
```

Using `only` ensure that you only import the function `random` and any other non-R5RS construct present in `racket/base`.